# product image in png format showing black background on product detail page

Tags: product-images, magento-2.1.9, product-detail-page

I have uploaded a ".png" format image for a product at backend and it shows black background at detail page at front.

I want to show it as it is with png format and with no background.

[image]

I have tried in `etc/view.xml` like this :

```
 <image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
     <width>800</width>
     <height>800</height>
     <transparency>true</transparency>
     <background>[255, 255, 255]</background>
  </image>
```

but not working.
Any other suggestion please.

Comment: please run the image resize command and check once

Comment: you can also set background color of the div in which image is shown...so that transparat color will not display black color

Answer (score 0):

Please try using one more parameter I.e.

```
<image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
     <width>800</width>
     <height>800</height>
     <frame>false</frame>
     <transparency>false</transparency>
</image>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have already tried but not working

Comment: have you use all comands after changes ?